# Using php with js and bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I don't know if I am doing this correctly and would like some advice please.

```
var housetype = '<?php print strtolower($item->post_title); ?>';

$(".outside-link").click(function() {
   $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
   $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
   $($(this).attr("data-toggle-tab")).parent("li").addClass("active");
   $("#showhome"+housetype).addClass('active fade in');  
});
```

I have a list of housetypes. Each has a name or "post_title". I have a button at the top of the page and I want to use that to select a tab at the bottom of the page.

I need to use the housetype post_title to find the correct tab i.e "showhomehousetitle" is the name of the correct tab, so I am trying to use PHP to call the name, but I just get this error:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #showhome<?php print strtolower($item->post_title); ?>`

I know I am probably doing this completely the wrong way, but I just can't work out what to do.

Update. This is a Wordpress site and I am using an external js file which I have enqued in functions.php. Don't know if that helps clarify.

Comment: Can we see the existing HTML markup for the buttons and the IDs that you've generated for the tabs.

Comment: That's not the problem. When I enter the name of the housetype manually the link works and the correct tab is openend. My problem is with using php in a js file.

Comment: I've just realised that I put the error message in quotes and it didn't display the full error message. I've updated it.

Comment: You can't use `<?php` inside .js files. you need to send the info there as JSON. you can use the `<?php tag` only in a .php files..

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks